# How can I collect strings across different component in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, string, spring-boot, file, components

To avoid to open and close many times a file I would like create a string across different component and finally write it in a file.

For example, I have these 3 jobs to run in main:

```
main() {
   createFile();
   job1.execute();
   job2.execute();
   job3.execute();
   storeFile();
}
```

and in each job I would like to do this:

```
execute(){
   file.append("string");
}
```

Which is the best way?

Actually I'm using this component:

```
@Component
public class OutputGeneratorImpl implements OutputGenerator {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void writeToFile(String path, String filename, String output, boolean append) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path + File.separator + filename, append))) {
            writer.write(output);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Could not write to file {} {}", filename, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing file as a parameter is not an option in your case?

Comment: No, no input parameters and void as output. I think I need to create a component.